# Find mesh islands for transform(Geometry Nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes

This nodes for smoothly transform one mesh into another. When moving vertex from mesh-1 position to the mesh-2 position, islands (and edge flow) are not consider. How to make the vertices pass only within the same island? And, if possible, consider the following edge flows.
[image: transform sample]

Comment: Hi. This does not seem like something someone will just know without trying things out. I think, with a question that specific and complex, you should definitely share a blend file with a working example to help people not waste their time on recreating the nodes to test this. You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ I think that will increase your chances for getting a good answer.

Comment: you could try isolating the islands by index. for that I would take the bounding box range (*attribute statistics* input *position* output *range*, or *bounding box* max minus min) and multiply it by the island index (times 2 for extra padding), and then set the position based on that. that way the islands will only be able to sample the island on the other mesh this the same index, since they are with their own isolated space per se